# Is there a way to track the number of days since a dialog message was dismissed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wish to display a dialog message to the user once a month. If the user dismisses the message, then I would restart the timer and display it 30 days later.

I've looked at various packages such as rate my app, which tracks minimum days however this solely works for app ratings and not generic dialog messages.

I expect the dialog to show upon first launch, then every 30 days after the message has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the DateTime class to capture the time when the dialog is displayed

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
```

You can use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) which has scheduling.

```
var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
        new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30));
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails('your other channel id',
        'your other channel name', 'your other channel description');
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails();
NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
    0,
    'scheduled title',
    'scheduled body',
    scheduledNotificationDateTime,
    platformChannelSpecifics);
```